# Nginx filtering message before proxy

Tags: nginx

I have been digging into creating a custom filtering module written in C that can process post messages. Read the json payload, make a decision whether to proxy the message or return a 204 to the client.

I am having trouble reading the payload of the message, I have read through quite a few of the modules but am missing something. I have tried quite a few ways to parse the payload but can't seem to figure out how to just simply print it.

I have read through the echo module, redis module, Evan Miller's documentation, etc.

I know that I need to read the full message before I can process the payload but the callback has got me confused. I don't really understand the callback in ngx_http_read_client_request_body. I have tried to read the code but there really is almost no documentation in the code.

In the code below I have tried multiple things to get the request body, I tried reading r->request_body->buf, bufs once the full body was read. When I try to print the request body, I get segfault. I think the echo module would have been the closest to what I wanted to do but I got confused in the ngx_http_echo_wev_handler on how it was processing the request.

```
static ngx_int_t ngx_http_ortb_handler(ngx_http_request_t *r) {
    ngx_int_t rc;

    ngx_flag_t read_body;

    if (r->method != NGX_HTTP_POST) {
        read_body = 1;
    }

    ngx_log_error(NGX_LOG_ERR, r->connection->log, 0, "Received Post");

    if (read_body) {
        rc = ngx_http_read_client_request_body(r, ngx_http_upstream_init);
        if (rc >= NGX_HTTP_SPECIAL_RESPONSE) {
            return rc;
        }
        ngx_log_error(NGX_LOG_ERR, r->connection->log, 0, "return code %ld", rc);

        // What do I need to do here to read the body. 


    } else {
        r->main->count++;
        rc = ngx_http_discard_request_body(r);
        if (rc != NGX_OK) {
            return rc;
        }
        ngx_http_upstream_init(r);
    }

    return NGX_DECLINED;
}
```

Comment: Body is not ready at this phase. You should use ngx_http_read_client_request_body() to set a body handler callback.It's called once entire body has been read.

Comment: http://www.serverphorums.com/read.php?5,79835